# Firestore query issues

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having an issue where I run this function:

```
    static func getAllJokes(reset: Bool, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        Utilities.getDadJokes(reset: reset) {
            print("Dad Jokes Pass, array = \(DadJokes.dadJokes)")
            Utilities.getAssistantJokes(reset: reset) {
                print("Assistant Jokes Pass, array = \(AssistantJokes.assistantJokes)")
                Utilities.getKnockKnockJokes(reset: reset) {
                    print("Knock Knock Jokes Pass, array = \(KnockKnockJokes.knockKnockJokes)")
                    Utilities.getRandomJokes(reset: reset) {
                        print("Random Jokes Pass, array = \(RandomJokes.randomJokes)")
                        completion()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

getDadJokes:

```
            db.collection("jokes").document("Dad Jokes").addSnapshotListener { document, error in
                //check for error
                if error == nil {
                    //check if document exists
                    if document != nil && document!.exists {
                        if let JokeNum = document!.get("JokeNum") as? Int {
                            self.countDadJokes = JokeNum
                            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(JokeNum, forKey: "countDadJokes")
                            print("DadJokeNum = \(self.countDadJokes)")
                        }
//                        var DadJokes.dadJokes.count = 1
                        print("count = \(DadJokes.dadJokes.count)/\(self.countDadJokes)")
                        print("countDadJoke = \(self.countDadJokes)")
                        self.jokes.removeAll()
                        if reset == true {
                            DadJokes.dadJokes.removeAll()
                        }
//                        for _ in 0...self.countDadJokes {
                        while DadJokes.dadJokes.count <= self.countDadJokes {
//                            print("count = \(DadJokes.dadJokes.count)/\(self.countDadJokes)")
                            if let Joke = document!.get("\(DadJokes.dadJokes.count + 1)") as? String {
                                print("DadJokeNum = \(self.countDadJokes)")
                                if Utilities.jokes.contains("\(Joke) - From Dad Jokes") {}else {
                                    Utilities.jokes.append("\(Joke) - From Dad Jokes")
                                    DadJokes.dadJokes.append(Joke)
                                    UserDefaults.standard.set(DadJokes.dadJokes, forKey: defaults.dadJokes.rawValue)
                                    Utilities.updateJokesDefaults()
                                    print("countDadJokesSaved = \(DadJokes.dadJokes.count)")
                                    print("DadJokesSaved = \(DadJokes.dadJokes)")
                                }
                                print("Dad Joke: \(Joke)")
                                //print("count = \(DadJokes.dadJokes.count)/\(self.countDadJokes)")
                                if DadJokes.dadJokes.count == self.countDadJokes {
                                    completion()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

runs fine, but then when I run getAssistantJoke (the same thing):

```
            print("assistant get running")
            db.collection("jokes").document("Assistant Jokes").addSnapshotListener { document, error in
                //check for error
                if error == nil {
                    //check if document exists
                    if document != nil && document!.exists {
                        if let JokeNum = document!.get("JokeNum") as? Int {
                            self.countAssistantJokes = JokeNum
                            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(JokeNum, forKey: defaults.countAssistantJokes.rawValue)
                            print("DadJokeNum = \(self.countDadJokes)")
                        }
//                        var DadJokes.dadJokes.count = 1
                        print("count = \(AssistantJokes.assistantJokes.count)/\(self.countAssistantJokes)")
                        print("countAssistantJokes = \(self.countAssistantJokes)")
                        if reset == true {
                            AssistantJokes.assistantJokes.removeAll()
                        }
//                        for _ in 0...self.countDadJokes {
                        while AssistantJokes.assistantJokes.count <= self.countAssistantJokes {
//                            print("count = \(AssistantJokes.assistantJokes.count)/\(self.countAssistantJokes)")
                            if let Joke = document!.get("\(DadJokes.dadJokes.count + 1)") as? String {
                                print("AssistantJokeNum = \(self.countAssistantJokes)")
                                if Utilities.jokes.contains("\(Joke) - From Assistant Jokes") {}else {
                                    Utilities.jokes.append("\(Joke) - From Assistant Jokes")
                                    AssistantJokes.assistantJokes.append(Joke)
                                    UserDefaults.standard.set(AssistantJokes.assistantJokes, forKey: defaults.assistantJokes.rawValue)
                                    Utilities.updateJokesDefaults()
                                    print("countAssistantJokesSaved = \(AssistantJokes.assistantJokes.count)")
                                    print("AssistantJokesSaved = \(AssistantJokes.assistantJokes)")
                                }
                                print("Assistant Joke: \(Joke)")
//                                print("count = \(AssistantJokes.assistantJokes.count)/\(self.countAssistantJokes)")
                                if AssistantJokes.assistantJokes.count == self.countAssistantJokes {
                                    completion()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It stops at firebase query. The documents and everything exist, therefor, what's the issue? Everything exists and I am truly stumped. My goal is to retrieve a ton of data and display a random subject. I feel like this should be easier than it is.

Here is my firebase setup:
[image: Assistant Jokes]
[image: Dad Jokes]

Comment: Nobody even knows what a guy named getAssistantJoke is.  Utilities?  Where does it come from?

Comment: @ElTomato What do you mean?

Comment: Some of that code could do with a lot of refactoring. And... if you're using snapshot listeners, is there any purpose for the completion blocks?

Comment: Also... when you say you're trying to get all the jokes... why is that? Also... why do you have different types of joke separated? Would it not be better to have a collection called `jokes` and then make each joke a document in that collection with a `type` or something (if you need to do something different per type).

Comment: Also, please remember that variables should begin with a lowercase letter. `if let Joke` should be `if let joke`. It makes it much harder to work out whats happening when you don't follow conventions like this.

Comment: And this... `if Utilities.jokes.contains("\(Joke) - From Dad Jokes") {} else { do stuff }` should be `if !Utilities.jokes.contains("\(Joke) - From Dad Jokes") { do stuff }` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like the main problem here is the way in which you are modelling the data in Firestore.

You have a collection called `jokes` but then a document called `Assistant Jokes`, `Dad Jokes`, etc...

I think a much better structure would be for each document to be a single joke inside the `jokes` collection. Use an "auto id" for each joke and then put a type inside the joke document.

The fact that you have to maintain a `JokeNum` next to your list of jokes is a sign that something is wrong.

By structuring this way you would then be able to get all jokes or filter the jokes by a particular type etc...

Your code is super complex at the moment but I think the best approach is to structure your data in a way that helps your code.

Comment: How would I assign type? Can you show an example of sorts? Also, In my current system there can't be a duplicate, could I replicate this by doing what your suggesting?

Comment: I decided to do it all by array on Firestore, thank you.